# Trying to Extract URL's from a Website Using Web Harvest

Tags: java, webharvest

I'm trying to extract the URL's of a website that doesn't have a sitemap. I'm using the [Web Harvest tool](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net)

I have no idea about Java or coding. Could someone please help me out with using this tool.

I want it to run on a specific website (e.g. example.com) and extract every single URL from that website.

Answer (score 1):

Example.com is not a very good example, as it has only one link! :)

Here's my code with some annotations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config>
        <!-- 1: provide inputs           -->  
        <script><![CDATA[
                url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635763/trying-to-extract-urls-from-a-website-using-web-harvest";

                output_path = "C:/webharvest/"; 
                file_name = "urllist.txt";              
                output_file = output_path + file_name;                  

            ]]></script>

        <!-- 5 : save the resulting list in a variable       -->    
        <var-def name="urls">
            <!-- 4 : select only links (outputs a list variable)         -->    
            <xpath expression='//a/@href'>
                <!-- 3 : convert it to XML, for querying         --> 
                <html-to-xml>
                    <!-- 2 : load the page       -->  
                    <http url="${url}"/>
                </html-to-xml>
            </xpath>
        </var-def>

        <!-- 7: write to output file         -->  
        <file action="write" path="${output_file}">
            <!-- 6 : convert the list variable into a string with each link on a new line        -->  
            <text delimiter="${sys.cr}${sys.lf}">
            <var name="urls" />
            </text>
        </file>              

</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go through Web harvest user manual at http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php which has multiple number of examples.